# Saving many plots in files

Tags: plotting, export

I made a table of ten plots:

```
Table[Plot[u[t, x] /. wws, {x, -10, 10}], {t, 0, 10, 1}]
```

I want to save them all to my file system. I know, that I can save each plot separataly by "Save as...", but it's tedious. Can anybody offer anything that will automate this (because in future it will be 50 plots)?

Answer (score 2):

```
plots = Table[Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}], {t, 0, 10, 1}];
names = ToString@StringForm["~/Plot``.pdf", #] & /@ ToString /@ Range@Length@plots;
Export[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread@{names, plots}
```

Giving ten different plots exported in `PDF`.

Comment: doh, you type faster.

Comment: @bobthechemist Well.., I also looked for duplicates.. :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to `Map` and `Export` routine:

```
plots = Table[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], {a, 1, 10}]
MapIndexed[Export[ToString[First@#2] <> ".png", #1] &, plots]
```

This stores the files with names 1.png, 2.png, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety and to deal with ordering issues that some times arise with 1,10,2 by padding left with zeros. This assumes that `plots` contains list of graphics objects:

```
MapThread[
 Export["plot" <> #1 <> ".pdf", #2] &, {IntegerString[#, 10, 3] & /@ 
   Range[Length@plots], plots}]
```

File will be "plot001.pdf","plot002.pdf",etc